# how should I use order by on distinct in entities

Tags: sql, .net, linq-to-entities, entity, sql-order-by

I have this code

```
     var chats = (from c in _entities.Chats
        where c.SenderId == userId || c.ReceiverId == userId

            select new ChatList()
             {
              Logo = c.SenderId != userId ? c.Company.LogoUrl:c.Company1.LogoUrl,
              Name = c.SenderId != userId? c.Company.CompanyPersonName:c.Company1.CompanyPersonName,
            UserId = c.SenderId!=userId ?c.Company.CompanyId : c.Company1.CompanyId 
            }
   ).Distinct();
```

how should I add , "order by" like this :

```
ORDER BY c.SenderId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `OrderBy`at the end of it:

```
   var chats = (from c in _entities.Chats
    where c.SenderId == userId || c.ReceiverId == userId

        select new ChatList()
         {
          Logo = c.SenderId != userId ? c.Company.LogoUrl:c.Company1.LogoUrl,
          Name = c.SenderId != userId? c.Company.CompanyPersonName:c.Company1.CompanyPersonName,
        UserId = c.SenderId!=userId ?c.Company.CompanyId : c.Company1.CompanyId 
        }
    ).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.UserId)
```

Comment: thank you, it works, but how about orderBy new field : like "c.date", the new problem is I can't call .Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.date)

Comment: you do not have `date` in your `select` if you include it in there you can order by it